# Sending multiple email attachments via Marketing Cloud dynamically

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to send multiple attachments via Marketing Cloud. We have the Attachment feature enabled and the below code works for a single attachment. However I wanted to attach multiple attachments based on subscriber ID, as we have a Data Extension (Invoices) that has SubscriberKey, Invoice number and date. We invoice monthly and would like to send all invoices related to a Subscriber Key in one email. Is this possible to do?

Our invoices are of minimal size, so we are not worried about file size, as the most we would have attached is 5 invoices to one subscriber key.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
%%[

var @invoiceid
var @fileName

set @invoiceid = AttributeValue("invoiceid")
set @fileName = concat("invoice_", @invoiceid, ".pdf")

AttachFile("FTP", @fileName, @fileName)

]%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many attachments, I would consider a loop. Lookup all the rows in the Invoice Data Extension and attach the files. How to do this has been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28859278).

If it is just a few attachments, I would just add the different attachments to the sending data extension: Attachment_1, Attachment_2 and conditionally (If not empty) duplicate the attachment code you already have as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27353466).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You simply need to run `AttachFile` once for each of the files you need to attach. You should use `LookupRows` function to get all the invoiceids for the particular recipient.

Be aware that most ISPs limit the attachment size they allow through to the inbox. This is calculated as a total of all the attachments on a single email.